# adding gutter to bootstrap with just CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout, fluid, gutter

I need to do a 3-column layout that matches the original design (in InDesign/Photoshop) as much as possible, and the requirements are using the responsive/fluid version of Bootstrap.

I either can't get them aligned center (example 1--the closest to what I am trying to achieve), can't get them to stop resizing the image and text without a huge gap (example 2), or I can't figure out how to do the vertical rules without messing up the percentage-based sizes (example 3). The gutters are giving me woes, because they are not wide enough and I do not know LESS and don't know how to modify Bootstrap directly.

The 3 columns need more space between them, they need to be centered on the page for larger sizes, and they need a vertical rule inserted between them. The images need to be the same size and the text should flow exactly the same.

Here are the portions of my code concerning the three different ways I have tried to do this.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<!-- Column 1 -->        
<div class="span4">
      <div class="threecolumn1stcolumnA">
      <img class="imagepadding" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="institutes" />
      <h2>&mdash; institutes &mdash;</h2>
      <p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del</p>
            </div>
    </div>
<!-- Column 2 -->        

    <div class="span4">
      <div class="threecolumn2ndcolumnA">
      <img class="imagepadding" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="centers" /><h2>&mdash; centers &mdash;</h2>
      <p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del </p>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Column 3 -->        

    <div class="span4">
      <div class="threecolumn3rdcolumnA">
      <img class="imagepadding" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="giving" /><h2>&mdash; giving &mdash;</h2>
      <p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del</p>         
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>           

<div class="row-fluid">
<!-- Column 1 -->        
<div class="span4">
      <div class="threecolumn1stcolumnB">
      <img class="imagepadding" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="institutes" />
      <h2>&mdash; institutes &mdash;</h2>
      <p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del</p>
            </div>
    </div>
<!-- Column 2 -->        

    <div class="span4">
      <div class="threecolumn2ndcolumnB">
      <img class="imagepadding" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="centers" /><h2>&mdash; centers &mdash;</h2>
      <p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del </p>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Column 3 -->        

    <div class="span4">
      <div class="threecolumn3rdcolumnB">
      <img class="imagepadding" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="giving" /><h2>&mdash; giving &mdash;</h2>
      <p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del</p>         
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
<div class="row-fluid">
<!-- Column 1 -->
<div class="span12">
<div class="threecolumn1stbox">
<img class="imagepadding" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="institutes" />
<h2>— institutes —</h2><p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del</p></div>
<div class="threecolumn2ndbox">
<img class="imagepadding" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="centers" />
<h2>&mdash; centers &mdash;</h2><p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del </p></div>
<div class="threecolumn3rdbox">
<img class="imagepadding" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="giving" />
<h2>&mdash; giving &mdash;</h2><p>Rae con core maximil earum solo cum namusa suntiatur, optate pos eum id quo mod ea simusciunt, nisqui anducita volore si sinust rae est et in restrum quaeped mo ma veliquo diciur, undam aut et et as sequaspis essitis alis unt, si dolut etur? Quid ma naturem perior ame sumet auta ni conessi te plis que nusda volorei uritas ad es dolorepero volorer spelecea none et repudit eliquunt optatem nobis andis del</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.threecolumn1stcolumnA{
padding: 0 20px 0 45px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-left:1px;}
.threecolumn2ndcolumnA{
padding: 0 20px 0 45px;
margin-top:30px;
border-left:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
.threecolumn3rdcolumnA{
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
margin-top:30px;
border-left:1px solid #d7d7d7;}

.threecolumn1stcolumnB {
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
margin-top:30px;
border-right:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
.threecolumn2ndcolumnB{box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
margin-top:30px;}
.threecolumn3rdcolumnB{
    box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
margin-top:30px;
border-left:1px solid #d7d7d7;}

.threecolumn1stbox{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
width:33.333333%;
float:left;
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
margin-left:1px;}
.threecolumn2ndbox{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
width:33.333333%;
float:left;
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
border-left:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
.threecolumn3rdbox{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
width:33%;
float:left;
padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
border-left:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and a smaller example of your code?

Comment: You can use the Bootstrap Customizer (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) to customize the grid if needed.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/RRwRv/

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get logged in again with the account that I posted this topic/question with. I tried out Brett's idea several weeks ago, but was unable to comment. Thank you guys for helping me with some advice. I pretty much found equally spaced dividers, with completely centered content in each span/column to be basically impossible in a 12 column responsive layout, at least with default gutters. Brett's solution was the smartest/most ingenius of all of the ones I tried, but still resulted in a group of three columns that were no longer completely centered on the page. It's perhaps possible that with a custom bootstrap with gutters removed that something could be created, but I never tried that. It may also be possible if the bootstrap site isn't responsive, but this site had to be responsive, so that wasn't an option.

In the end, I just decided that those vertical dividers would just have to be left off.